# Deadlocks in innodb [ transactions having locks on same page]

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

MySQL v8.0.23

Below is out put of 'show engine innodb status'

### LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK

```
2023-04-13 09:25:19 0x7f65e5d5c700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 667552221, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 3662804, OS thread handle 140095257151232, query id 3727267470 x.x.x.x x.x.x.x admin update
Insert into acl (`id`) values ("456085798018673829")

*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 14 page no 198202 n bits 80 index bGhRuWwvrN of table `testdb`.`acl` trx id 667552221 lock_mode X locks gap before rec
Record lock, heap no 10 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 0



*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 14 page no 198202 n bits 80 index bGhRuWwvrN of table `testdb`.`acl` trx id 667552221 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 10 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 0



*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 667552222, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 3662785, OS thread handle 140056638150400, query id 3727267471 x.x.x.x x.x.x.x admin update
Insert into acl (`id`) values ("456085798018677418")

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 14 page no 198202 n bits 80 index bGhRuWwvrN of table `testdb`.`acl` trx id 667552222 lock_mode X locks gap before rec
Record lock, heap no 10 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 0



*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 14 page no 198202 n bits 80 index bGhRuWwvrN of table `testdb`.`acl` trx id 667552222 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 10 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 0
```

If you read 'HOLDS THE LOCK(S):' it shows same page no and space id for both transactions. t reads'lock_mode X' both both transactions, which means it's an x lock. Does this mean both transactions have acquired lock on same page? How can both transactions have x lock on same page?

Also, both appear to be waiting for same lock to be granted. How would that cause deadlock?

Table definition

```
    CREATE TABLE `ACL` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tenant_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `rce_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `rce_type` int NOT NULL,
  `aen_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `prs` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('ACTIVE','INACTIVE') NOT NULL,
  `elt_deny` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`tenant_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `bGhRuWwvrN` (`rce_id`,`rce_type`,`aen_id`,`prs`,`cname`,`tenant_id`),
  KEY `tenant_id$cname$prs$aen_id` (`tenant_id`,`cname`,`prs`,`aen_id`),
  KEY `FZhIAdwsXu` (`tenant_id`,`cname`,`rce_type`,`prs`,`aen_id`),
  KEY `FZhIAdwsXu123` (`tenant_id`,`cname`,`rce_type`,`aen_id`)
)
```

Comment: Can you post table and index definitions

Comment: updated my question with the definition of table

Comment: Yes, I've seen lots of deadlocks during INSERT when the table has both a PRIMARY KEY and a second UNIQUE KEY. I think MySQL does not lock these atomically, so the lock requests have a chance of interleaving, and therefore deadlock. It's unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

"lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting" -- sounds like a pessimistic "gap" lock.

Are there no ids between 456085798018673829 and 456085798018677418?  Then both `INSERTs` try adding a row in the same 'gap'.  InnoDB does not try to decide whether the two would collide.

Are those Inserts parts of long-running transactions?  I suggest the best way to work around this deadlock is to see if there is a way to speed up the transactions.

And, as always, be ready to discover the deadlock and replay the transaction that was ROLLBACK'd.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it only happens after I added "rewriteBatchedStatements=true" to my jdbc connection, pls check your configuration

Comment: We use this from a go application and do not set any such parameter called "rewriteBatchedStatements"